# OverGrive Ubuntu 18.04 Launch Issue

Tags: 18.04

I recently installed [OverGrive](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/overgrive/installation-instructions-ubuntu) , Installed successfully but it's not launching. I search answers but nothing is working out. Need help.

Tried launching from the terminal, Following error is coming-

command- `python2 /opt/thefanclub/overgrive/overgrive`

Output-
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "overgrive.py", line 53, in <module>
ImportError: No module named oauth2client.client`

Comment: That sounds like two separate questions - for the second one, see [Pip installing always results in error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/877372/pip-installing-always-results-in-error)

Comment: Actually, most of the answers I found had mentioned the pip installation. The primary problem is OverGrive launch.

Comment: All I can suggest is that you attempt to start it from the command line, using the command shown in the `Exec=` line of the `overgrive.desktop` file, and [edit] your question with any error messages

Comment: Done. followed other answers for the error. Still stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue and fixed it right now. You'll want to install `oauth2client` for `python2`. The `pip` process for `python2` is called `pip2`. You can verify that:

```
$ which pip2
/usr/bin/pip2
```

Under which case

```
$pip2 install --upgrade oauth2client
```

fixes that component.

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal:

```
pip install --upgrade oauth2client
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and contacted the developer. He gave me the following advice, and it worked.

> Clear all trashed files from your Google Drive online Trash/Bin
>   folder. Delete the following files from your local Google Drive folder
>   and restart the program. .overgrive.cache .overgrive.auth
>
> You will find the setup screen again. Do the setup and click "Start
>   Sync"
>
> It does not download all the files again. It just "checks" every file
>   and rebuilds the local cache file. It takes time, but no files will be
>   downloaded if they exist already.